# Making requests

Tags: modal-verbs, tag-questions

As far as I know, there are 4 main ways of making requests which include modal verbs:

1. Can you do it?
2. Could you do it?
3. Will you do it?
4. Would you do it?

Therefore, the following requests should be correct as well, right?

1. Hold this for me, can you?
2. Hold this for me, could you?
3. Hold this for me, will you?
4. Hold this for me, would you?

Comment: I disagree there's any basis for calling your first set of sentences the four "main" ways, to the exclusion of all other ways. There are many other ways to make requests, and none take any priority over the others.

Comment: I meant, those which include modal verbs

Comment: I still don't see how that's a useful category, and there's no rule that says the first set being correct means the second set is correct too. A counterexample: another possible request is, "Might you do it?", but "Hold this for me, might you?" is definitely wrong.

Comment: Also, is your question about whether the second set are all correct, or whether there's a rule-based connection between the first and second set?

Comment: Just asking whether the second is correct

Comment: English grammar books provide such sentences as common examples of polite requests. I beg your pardon if I misused some of the terms  in my question. I am not a native speaker nor a linguist.

Comment: Surprisingly, your example with "might you do it" is not seen in grammar books. As I understand, "May you do it?" and "Might, you do it?" are also correct, right?

Comment: *May/might you do it?* are a valid construction, but they mean something different.  *Might you...?* sounds like asking about the possibility of something, like, "I see you can't log into the website.  Might you have put in the wrong password?"  *May you...?* sounds like asking about permission, for example, "May you leave school during the day?"